# Copy files to backup location and rename using Lastwritetime

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to write a script that copies files from their original location to a backup location. Upon copying to the backup location I'd like the files to be renamed to include the lastwritetime in the name.

ex: \\server1\C$\Logs\Logfile-1.txt (last written to Wednesday, December 20, 2017 5:00:27 AM) copied to \\backupserver\c$\LogBackups\Server1Logfile20171220050027.txt

The program generating the logfiles iterates them with a -1, -2, -3, etc as they reach a certain size.

I have a csv which contains the following information

```
OldFilePath,NewFilePath,NewFileName
\\server1\c$\Log\LogFile-*.txt,\\backupserver\c$\LogBackups\,Server1LogFile
\\server2\c$\Log\LogFile-*.txt,\\backupserver\c$\LogBackups\,Server2LogFile
\\server3\c$\Log\LogFile-*.txt,\\backupserver\c$\LogBackups\,Server3LogFile
```

Here is the script that I've got so far.

```
import-csv \\backupserver\c$\scripts\test.csv | foreach-object {
$FilePath = $_.OldFilePath
$NewFilePath = $_.NewFilePath
$NewFileName = $_.NewFileName

copy-item -path $_.OldFilePath -Destination "$NewFilePath$NewFileName$LastWriteTime.txt"
}
```

I've tried the following commands to set the $LastWriteTime variable and, so far, haven't been able to correctly format the outputs.

```
$LastWriteTime = Get-ItemPropertyValue -path \\server1\C$\Logfile-1.txt -name LastWriteTime | 
Format-list Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second
```

&

```
$LastWriteTime = Get-ChildItem $OldFilePath | select LastWriteTime
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a DateTime $dt, you can format it like so:

```
$dt = [DateTime]::Parse((get-item D:\temp\grinder.jpg).LastWriteTime)
$fmt = "{0:N4}{0:N2}{0:N2}{0:N2}{0:N2}{0:N2}" -f $dt.Year, $dt.Month, $dt.Day, $dt.Hour, $dt.Minute, $dt.Second
```

Which gives:

```
20171220110535
```

for

```
Wednesday, December 20, 2017 11:05:35 AM
```

From this, you should be able to make progress on rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I needed!